# Using Time Series Tables with Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, time-series, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm trying to use Redshift time series tables with Kinesis Firehose but didn't find a way to setup Firehose correctly.
[Here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=725182) is a similar question on AWS Developer Forum

Comment: I am using exactly the same structure. At what stage are you stuck?